# Odd automatic mouse Movement after Computer Resumes from Hibernation

Tags: windows-7, mouse, automation

Recently, i started noticing something odd happening with my computer.  It is currently running Windows 7 64 Professional.

Whats happening is this.  When the computer comes out of  hibernation, over the past two days, I'll notice my mouse pointer moving 'up' towards the top of the screen in short little 'hops'.  I have two mice and a joystick plugged into the computer, and none of the 3 are moving. Yet the mouse will 'jump' upwards (it'll be in one spot, then either flicker to the new location directly above that spot, or it will quickly move upwards).

It usually seems random when it does it, but just recently, i had to quite literally 'fight' it to get down to the start button to restart the computer (which clears this odd effect).

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?  I've ran an AV  program twice and its come back clean.. nothing has been installed that i don't know about...  I'm stumped.

Comment: If the mice are laser-based then it might be because of surface irregularities and some sort of latent command. Try a rough surface (like a sheet of paper) and check if it happens again.

Comment: This is not a virus, it's probably a latent command as @DoktoroReichard suggests. I've seen it many times (not just after a resume from hibernate) with certain mice and the best you can do is either unplug it and replug it to reset the connection, or restart the computer.

Comment: I do have one laser mouse, but its sitting on its own little pad and dosnt move.  Even moved it myself a bit during one of these episodes to see if that changed anything.  Mouse still jumped =)

Answer (score -1):

What might be happening is that the mouse is on an irregular surface and causing it to move. Only way to be sure is unplugging all the moues, and if the movement continues then... YOU ARE INFECTED, not really. Another thing that causes these movements is that you might not be connecting the moues correctly. Or cheek is you have something on you keyboard or if a button is being pressed. Luck!

Comment: This is not accurate. There are many things that can cause irregular mouse movement besides "infection".